# What's the meaning of 'secure the door'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, expressions

I am always bit confused with the word, secure. To me, it means making something safe and stable. But I feel sometimes Americans use the word in the sense I never use the security in my country such as secure a job. You get the job then you get to work hard. Where do you get the sense of security?

Anyway, with the expression 'secure the door', does it mean 'lock the door for security'? or does it mean that check the door if everything is ok such as if lock is ok, if the door board is intact, etc.

============

The question is closed and I do not agree with it. As a foreigner, it's not always easy to find the suitable meaning of a word in a dictionary especially, a word has many meanings. For example, to the mother tongue of English, they might think it's so clear to apply meaning number 3 of dictionary but to the foreigner, it looks like meaning number 1 and 4 makes sense. Of course, I looked at the dictionary and I couldn't narrow down to one. And I believe that's one of the reasons why this forum exists. Put your cloudy perception of the English on to the concrete base.

Comment: If you glance in a dictionary, one of the meanings is "fasten". (No connection, whatsoever, to "security" in the sense of say a security guard.)  It's completely commonplace in English that one word has a number of completely different meanings.

Comment: Next time, please share your research. Users cannot possibly know which dictionary you have consulted and which definitions give you pause for thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The OED lists nine different senses of the verb *to secure*, and some have as many as eight different sub-senses.**

As regards the ones the OP mentions in the question, ***securing a job*** fits under sense 3f, -*to make sure (a person) obtains something*:

> 1989   J. M. Dillard Lost Years xii. 257   This would secure him a
> promotion, perhaps even a position on the Presidium. 2004   Knowledge
> Apr. 36/1   At the same time, that mixtape was also about to secure
> her a slot at Swerve, Fabio's long running midweeker.

And as for ***securing a door*** this is most likely being used in sense 5a - *...to fasten or do up; to close (a door, window, etc.) tightly; to lock*:

> 1994   I. Welsh Stoke Newington Blues in Acid House 33   A series of
> locks click open and Ange looks at me... She bades me enter and
> secures the door.

Or- as a long shot - it could have the meaning of sense 1g - *to fence off, or to enclose by a barrier*

> 1907   R. E. Thompson Nature, Mirror of Grace vii. 123   [The temple]
> was mounted on an artificial hill..and secured by a wall of brick some
> twenty feet thick.

Comment: The last sense needs "by", so it doesn't really fit.

Comment: Well that's only because it's written in the passive voice. One could equally say: "...and a wall of brick some twenty feet thick secured the artificial hill on which the temple was mounted."

Comment: sense 3f for "securing a job"  is the sense in which I understand it too. Finding an opening, going to interviews, signing contracts, and so on are a bit like a quest with a prize at the end, which is something which is initially out of your grasp but with endeavour you might grab (secure). To justify this, in the same way, you'd not normally say you have "secured food" because it's not such a quest. But you can imagine in a post-apocalyptic scenario, or jpeople living on the streets (probably very similar experiences) you may well say someone has "secured food" because it was an epic battle.

Answer (score 4):

You can usually find the answer to questions like this by looking in a good dictionary, for example the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/secure), which contains several definitions. Among them are two that are relevant to your question:

> to fasten one object firmly to another
> to get something, sometimes with difficulty

The first meaning is appropriate for a door, and means that you fasten the door firmly to something. This could mean locking, but could also relate to any other form of latch or catch that will fasten the door firmly. Securing the door would usually mean attaching it firmly the frame, but in the following sentence it means exactly the opposite:

> Secure the door to prevent it from closing behind you. - *[Facility fire brigade: principles and practice (2009)](https://www.google.co.id/books/edition/Facility_Fire_Brigade_Principles_and_Pra/_hy_DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22secure%20the%20door%22&pg=PA296&printsec=frontcover)*

The second meaning would relate to a job. Note that this usage is quite formal: you would not secure an ice cream.

Comment: I was just composing an answer relating to the second definition! If you have _secured a job_, you have finally got one and it is a definite offer.

Comment: @KateBunting You can, of course, also *secure tickets for the Centre Court* - which seems to fit in the same OED category - but I couldn't find an example.

Comment: I'll second that this is formal usage. I have secured (that is, obtained / acquired) ice cream on multiple occasions, however.  That isn't a *common* usage, but it's one someone speaking magniloquently might well use.

Answer (score 4):

On Lexico, the first defintion is:

> fixed or fastened so as not to give way, become loose, or be lost.

This can be applied to anything that might be loose, such as nuts and bolts. But it can also apply to doors.

Securing the door might mean locking it, it might mean merely closing it and checking that it can't blow open. It might even mean "block the door", or "fix it in an open position". You would use context to understand if you needed only to close, to lock or to brace the door.

Comment: It's interesting that on this list, there are thousands of questions of this form: *"Regarding word X, I can see clearly that in English it means Y and here are many examples of it in use meaning Y and I checked in the OED and it states that X means Y and I asked everyone in my office and school what X means and they said X means Y. However, it really **seems to me** that X should not mean Y. My question is, does X mean Y?"*  This odd **"seems to me"** phenom. happens much more in English than in other languages. (Perhaps because English is spectacularly fluid, irregular, illogical. IDK.)

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I find this phrase somewhat unnatural--*except* in the context of US military jargon. Are the Americans you are hanging out with associated with the US military or their contractors (who are often retired military)?

Within US military jargon, this would sound natural, but also "secure" is a somewhat overused and ambiguous word.

Depending on context, it could mean to lock the door, ensure it is locked, latch it closed, ensure it is latched closed, latch it open, or ensure it is latched open (latched open is commonly possible aboard ships, aircraft, and field shelters). It could mean to put a checkmark on a form certifying that you have done one of the actions listed for the end-of-day security checklist.

Or it could mean to keep your rifle pointed at the door to ensure no hostile person comes through or threatens your party. It could mean throw a grenade through the door. It could mean pass through the door and ensure no hostile persons are lurking on the other side.

There are probably several more possibilities I have not thought of. Very overused word. And now, let me share a US military joke about the over-use of the word "secure" this is pasted from https://upjoke.com/armed-forces-jokes. It's probably only funny to veterans of the US armed forces who have been exposed to the overuse and misuse of "secure."

> How to differentiate between the branches of the US armed forces:
> If you give the command "SECURE THE BUILDING", here is what the different services >would do:
>
> The NAVY would turn out the lights and lock the doors.
>
> The ARMY would surround the building with defensive fortifications, tanks and >concertina wire.
>
> The MARINE CORPS would assault the building, using overlapping fields of fire from >all appropriate points on the perimeter. They will kill everybody inside and set up >headquarters.
>
> The AIR FORCE would take out a three-year lease with an option to buy the building.

Comment: That joke was the first thing I thought of on seeing this question.

Answer (score 0):

It means "lock the door".  In general, to secure a space is to control entry and egress.  To secure a building is to get control of it, in particular of its entrances.  To secure a town means to control it miltarily, although in principle a police force might suffice to secure a town.  But we don't speak of securing a country:  we speak of conquering or occupying it.   You can speak of securing its borders, however.

These actions don't necessarily connote an increase in security.  If the forces that secure doors, spaces, buildings, or town are authoritarian, you might well say that securing these things leads to *less* security, not more.

Comment: The correct answer, oddly downvoted.

Comment: I thought it odd, too.

Comment: Securing a place does not imply imposing control on its occupants. Hadrian secured his English territory from the Scots by building a wall. That doesn't imply control of the English populace. PS: I could have written "secured England from the Scots".